Can't hear remote participant audio output on Samsung Galaxy A9+ tablet speakers using Chrome, Opera, or Edge running WebRTC voice call application
I use WebRTC for a voice call application running in the browser. In testing my app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A9+ (SM-X210) on Android 14, I've observed that when using the Chrome, Edge, or Opera browsers I am unable to hear the remote participant's audio stream coming out of the device speakers, but I am able to confirm it is being received via a volume indicator I built that's displayed in the UI. The stream is active, but nothing can be heard. I've granted all required permissions to the browsers to play sound. I just use an audio tag and set the srcObject to the MediaStream object once I have it, so I don't believe it should be Web Audio API issues. Interestingly, I am able to hear the audio output when using Firefox or Samsung Internet Browser (SIB). On desktop, this problem doesn't exist, it only happens on the three aforementioned browsers running on the tablet.
I have tried many different approaches to resolve the issue, including a deep dive into browser autoplay policies, but the ONLY thing that fixes the problem is if I do not acquire the tablet's microphone via getUserMedia. Obviously this isn't a viable solution since the local participant should have their audio captured and streamed, but it leads me to believe there is perhaps some resource prioritization happening on the three affected browsers.
I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced something similar, or what technology would be the most likely culprit? It could be a Blink or Chromium issue, but to my knowledge Samsung Internet Browser is also Chromium-based, so it's surprising the issue isn't also seen there. It could be manufacturer-specific, or even specific to Android 14? I'm unable to reproduce the issue on an old Galaxy Tab A I have (SM-T510) running Android 11 on Chrome v123 which could lead me to believe it's an issue with Android 14, but if that's the case, why does it work on Firefox or SIB on Android 14? The number of possibilities seem endless, so I'm hoping someone can even just provide the best place to look.
The details on the tablet are:
Samsung SM-X210
8GB RAM
128 GB storage
Android 14
Google Chrome for Android: 124.0.6367.82
Happy to answer any questions and provide additional information that would help! Thank you!

I don't have enough reputation points to comment :( but wanted to let you know I have the identical tablet and am having the same exact issue, can only get audio output on Firefox consistently. There is one odd thing that can be done on the tablet which seems to give a temporary allowance for the audio, if you are in the web browser, click into audio settings, and change the volume, that seems to allow the audio feed to be heard, but the minute you leave the volume settings, it goes back to completely silent. Look forward to hearing if anyone has resolved this.

Thanks Jeff, appreciate your follow-up! I've filed a bug report with Chromium here if you'd like to comment or +1 it: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/336962422?pli=1
No resolution yet but I'm hopeful because this issue is a show-stopper for anyone looking to run their WebRTC-based app in Chrome on a Samsung tablet (which based on global market share would affect a huge number of users).

may I ask where you access the browser's audio settings? I've gone into Chrome's settings looking for anything similar (under Site settings too) but can't seem to find what you're referring to.

Exactly the same thing here! A9+ need it for stream sounds, most interfaces work, like fb videos etc, but if i open a audio browser source, nothing! not even on headset etc.
Works on phone and pc, tested 3 sites, so def an issue on the tablet

Please post answers and solutions only. If you have a comment then click 'Add a comment' under the original question

This is not a solution or answer
